# How to solve the issue of delay in getting results in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had created the following view,

```
SELECT     
   currency_cd, SUM(comprate) AS salary, employee_code,
   (SELECT SUM(c.comprate) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.employees_compensation AS c 
    INNER JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, comp_ratecd
        FROM dbo.employees_compensation
        WHERE (effdt = (SELECT MAX(effdt) AS Expr1
               FROM dbo.employees_compensation AS employees_compensation_1
               WHERE (employee_code = b.employee_code)
              )
       ) AND (employee_code = b.employee_code)
    GROUP BY 
       comp_ratecd) AS a ON c.id = a.id) AS salary1
FROM 
   dbo.employees_compensation AS b
GROUP BY 
   currency_cd, employee_code
```

It is working fine and giving the expected results. But the problem is it takes time in executing and giving the results. And sometime it gives error also like Timeout etc.. Could you help me in solving the issue?

Comment: which database server you are using? Avoid join on subqueries instead of this try to join with real tables or create a view for fixed join selection. And later fire the query on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should reorganize your DB? Create tables that will represents joins, for example.
If you don't care about timing you can avoid timeout error by creating *temprorary tables* or *virtual tables (aka views)*.
Avoid such a complex and nested expressions.